# Finding euler's number

Tags: linear-algebra

Good day.
I've been trying to understand the derivation of e. 
Since e is an expression that arises in the study of compound interest (based on Khan academy and wikipedia), I conducted an experiment: with ST as total sum, x as principal, I as interest rate in %/unit time, p as period of time, T as total time, n as the number of equal periods in total time, where p=T/n

Then, I tried to find the expressions of ST when p = 1,2 & 3. Results: when n=1, ST=x(1+IT); n=2, ST=x(1+IT/2)^2; n=3, ST=x(1+IT/3)^3. Resultant expression: ST=x(1+k/n)^n. Definition of e is the limit of (1+1/n)^n as n approaches infinity. How do I relate my expression with the definition?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/exponential-and-logarithmic-functions/e-and-the-natural-logarithm/v/e-through-compound-interest

Answer (score 3):

It is a theorem derived from the definition you quote that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac kn\right)^n=e^k$$
The easiest way to see it is to define $z=\frac nk$ and note
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac kn\right)^n=\lim_{z \to \infty}\left(1+\frac 1z\right)^{zk}\\=\lim_{z \to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac 1z\right)^z\right)^k\\=e^k$$